# cleaning data takes too much memory android

Tags: android

i'm trying to clear data of 50 browsers (root) using the snippet below. However, the process is too expensive and lags on my note 3, crashes on older devices sometimes. how do i make this process consume less resources? i'm assuming everyone has around 3 browsers, but it clears 50.

```
private void clearData1() {
    // UC
    String cmd = "pm clear com.UCMobile.intl";
    String cmd1 = "pm clear com.UCMobile";
    String cmd2 = "pm clear com.uc.browser.en";
    String cmd3 = "pm clear com.UCMobile.internet.org";
    String cmd4 = "pm clear uc.ucdl";
    // stock
    String cmd5 = "pm clear com.sec.android.app.sbrowser";
    String cmd6 = "pm clear com.htc.sense.browser";
    String cmd7 = "pm clear com.android.browser";
    // CM
    String cmd8 = "pm clear com.ksmobile.cb";
    // firefox
    String cmd9 = "pm clear org.mozilla.firefox";
    String cmd10 = "pm clear org.mozilla.firefox_beta";

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder().redirectErrorStream(true)
            .command("su");
    Process p = null;
    try {
        p = pb.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    StreamReader stdoutReader = new StreamReader(p.getInputStream(),
            CHARSET_NAME);
    stdoutReader.start();
    out = p.getOutputStream();
    try {
        out.write((cmd + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
        out.write((cmd1 + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
        out.write((cmd2 + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
        out.write((cmd3 + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
        out.write((cmd4 + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
        out.write((cmd5 + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
        out.write((cmd6 + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
        out.write((cmd7 + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
        out.write((cmd8 + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
        out.write((cmd9 + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
        out.write((cmd10 + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        out.write(("exit" + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String result = stdoutReader.getResult();
}
```

Comment: use background task, such as AsyncTask

Comment: [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code snippet

```
private class ClearData extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, String > {
    protected String doInBackground(Void...voids) {
        // UC
        String cmd = "pm clear com.UCMobile.intl";
        String cmd1 = "pm clear com.UCMobile";
        String cmd2 = "pm clear com.uc.browser.en";
        String cmd3 = "pm clear com.UCMobile.internet.org";
        String cmd4 = "pm clear uc.ucdl";
        // stock
        String cmd5 = "pm clear com.sec.android.app.sbrowser";
        String cmd6 = "pm clear com.htc.sense.browser";
        String cmd7 = "pm clear com.android.browser";
        // CM
        String cmd8 = "pm clear com.ksmobile.cb";
        // firefox
        String cmd9 = "pm clear org.mozilla.firefox";
        String cmd10 = "pm clear org.mozilla.firefox_beta";
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder().redirectErrorStream(true)
            .command("su");
        Process p = null;
        try {
            p = pb.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StreamReader stdoutReader = new StreamReader(p.getInputStream(),
            CHARSET_NAME);
        stdoutReader.start();
        out = p.getOutputStream();
        try {
            out.write((cmd + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
            out.write((cmd1 + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
            out.write((cmd2 + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
            out.write((cmd3 + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
            out.write((cmd4 + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
            out.write((cmd5 + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
            out.write((cmd6 + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
            out.write((cmd7 + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
            out.write((cmd8 + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
            out.write((cmd9 + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
            out.write((cmd10 + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            out.write(("exit" + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String result = stdoutReader.getResult();
        return result;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //Do what you want with the result
    }
}
```

And you call this sub class with this :
`new ClearData().execute();`

Comment: how do i detect if the process has completed? i want to go back when its done

Comment: in onPostExecute try call `finish()`